# Strange network proxy issue

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, centos, proxy

All of my external connections needs to go through a proxy, so for my user I've added this line to allow me to `wget` or `yum` freely

~/.bashrc

```
export http_proxy=http://10.50.24.125:8080/
```

The part above works great, but for a PHP script I have, I'm trying to use `php_curl` to fetch a file, so I'm defining the same proxy there too:

```
$curlHandle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXY, '10.50.24.125');

$out=curl_exec($curlHandle);
echo $out;
curl_close($curlHandle);
```

However, I don't see any results, and for some strange reason when I `netstat -n` while running the script, I can see the connection the script is trying to make, which is the strange part:

```
tcp        0      0 10.50.25.83:80              10.20.5.15:51194            TIME_WAIT
```

So instead of connecting to 10.50.24.125:8080 it's connecting to 10.20.5.15 on a random port, and the source port on local is 80?

Any ideas?

Note: running CentOS 5.6

Comment: That's not a connection in progress - it's one that was recently closed.  Does the script return immediately or hang?

Comment: @Brian returns immediately